# Custom List object in cookies

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

I want to store list of custom Objects in cookie.
Example scenario:
Lets say i have a product class. I want to store the list of products selected by customer in cookie, until he logs in.

(eg)
    class Product{
     int id;String name;float price;}

Since cookie allows only string, Possible solutions:
1) I can store it in a comma(,) seperated value in cookie. (ie)id:price,id:price
and manupulate everytime.
2) I can make the class implements serializable, create another wrapper which holds this list and add it in cookie 
(ie)class wrapper implements Serializable{List product;}

Option 1 does preliminary computation on string while option 2 gives me a class level control, so that i can do further manipulation directly when needed.
Please suggest me, which is the best option to go for.
Please let me know, pros and cons on both approach,.. Suggest me, if any best solution than this, if exists.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Deserialization from a cookie is a security risk!  http://www.infoq.com/news/2015/11/commons-exploit.  thatidiotguy's suggestion of a JSON string is perfect.  You can base64 encode the string too, which obscures the cookies contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using JSON to encode your objects and store that as a string in the cookie. This makes it easier to debug problems having to do with cookies since you can tell immediately what values the cookie is holding since JSON is human readable.

I just don't think this is a good use of Java serialization.